# Which word is best; "population", "pick" or "combination"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, hypernyms

Please look at the sentence below.

> The ________ of actors and actresses is very important in this movie I will make.

Which of the following three words fit best in the blank space?

- *population*, *pick* or *combination*

I myself like *pick* better.

Are there any better words?

Comment: I would pick "*The cast is very important*", ie. use Josh's suggestion but drop the "actors and actresses" as it's redundant.

Comment: Alternatively, to emphasise the "picking" of the cast: "The _casting_ of this movie is very important".

Answer (score 1):

[Cast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cast) is the term generally used to refer to: : (From TFD)

> - The actors in a play, movie, or other theatrical presentation.
> - In the performing arts, casting (or casting call) is a pre-production process for selecting a cast of actors, dancers, singers, models and other talent for a live or recorded performance.

I think *cast* covers the meaning of the three terms that you are suggesting. If you want to use one of them probably *pick/choice* fit best.